# Query to Return a value from a linked table in sql

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to develop an app for a driving school.

I have a table for instructors:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Instructori] 
(
    [nume]          NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [prenume]       NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [CNP]           CHAR(13)      NOT NULL,
    [Nastere]       SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Angajare]      SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    [IDmasina]      INT           NOT NULL,
    [IDCategorie]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [Sex]           NCHAR(1)      NOT NULL,
    [NrStudenti]    INT           NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [RataPromovare] DECIMAL(5, 2) NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [TotalStudenti] AS [dbo].Total_Stud(CNP),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Instructori] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CNP] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [Instr] 
         FOREIGN KEY ([IDCategorie]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Categorie] ([IDCategorie]),
);
```

One for Students:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Studenti] 
(
    [nume]                NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [prenume]             NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [Nastere]             SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Legislatie_p]        INT           NULL,
    [Categorii_dobandite] NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [Categorie]           INT           NOT NULL,
    [Data_examnen]        SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    [IDLectie]            INT           NOT NULL,
    [CNP]                 CHAR(13)      NOT NULL,
    [CNPI]                CHAR(13)      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Studenti] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CNP] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Categorie] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([Categorie]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Categorie] ([IDCategorie]),
    CONSTRAINT [Lectie] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([IDLectie]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Legislatie] ([IDLectie]),
    CONSTRAINT [Instructor1] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CNPI]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Instructori] ([CNP])
);
```

and one for cars named "Masina" which is not really relevant.

"Conducere" is the linking table between the 3 others, and it's only used to count how many hours each student drive.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Conducere] 
(
    [CNP_Instructor] CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    [IDMasina]       INT      NOT NULL,
    [CNP_Student]    CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    [Numar_ore]      INT      NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CNP_Instructor] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [Student] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CNP_Student]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Studenti] ([CNP]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Masina] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([IDMasina]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Masina] ([IDMasina]),
    CONSTRAINT [Instructor] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CNP_Instructor]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Instructori] ([CNP])
);
```

I already coded a function for the total number of students for each instructor.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Total_Stud(@CNP CHAR(13))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        (SELECT Count(CNP)
         FROM   Studenti
         WHERE  CNPI = @CNP)
END
```

I'm trying to find the students that have the same instructor(based on their CNP) and did not drive 30h yet. Students still in school ish.

Comment: It's great that we have some DDL here; which makes thigns really easy for us to understand your data structure (well done). We could, however, really do with some sample data and expected results to compliment it (preferable the sample data as `INSERT` statements to go with the great DDL we already have). Then we have everything we need to replicate your problem, and a clear goal in mind.

Comment: The goal is to make another function, similar to this, that return the number of students with the same instructor, which did not completed their hours(goal 30h) and put this number in the column NrStudenti in Instructori table.
  
An example would be this: 2 students have the same instructor, one has 30h of driving and one have 26. The function would return 1 to the column NrStudenti.

Comment: You seem focused on functions. Why? Scalar functions are generally inefficient when used. I suggest you focus on using tsql to generate the information you need. Decide later if there is a good reason and need for a function. And I suggest you think about your schema. I see potential flaws. You equate student and enrollment (or whatever term is appropriate). Can a person take a class multiple times? What happens if an instructor leaves? Same for student? Conducere has no primary key - that is a basic flaw too.

Comment: Numar_ore is int? Think again - stop blindly using datatypes. What is the maximum possible number of hours one can drive. I'm certain it is far less than 2 billion. And does that represent driving hours or classroom hours or both? Do you need datetime values in your schema? Or just dates? Again - think about what information you store.

Comment: Numar_ore has a rather generic value, and it represents the number for each student, I will add more constraints as I advance into the project.
I focused on functions because I am pretty new to sql, and this is a personal project with the scope of learning.
I have used functions because they seemed easy to understand( easier than views in my opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can SUM the hours for each student and filter the results by HAVING:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Student_Below_RequiredHours(@CNP CHAR(13),@RequiredHours int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        (SELECT CNP_Student
         FROM   [dbo].[Conducere]
         WHERE  CNP_Instructor = @CNP
         GROUP BY CNP_Student
         HAVING SUM([Numar_ore])<@RequiredHours)
END
```